Nginx proxy changing POST requests to GET on upstream server
I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy with SSL to route requests to a backend server. However, when I send POST requests, they’re received as GET requests on the backend.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.mydomain www.api.mydomain; 
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.mydomain www.api.mydomain;

    ssl_certificate /home/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/p.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3110;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

When I send a POST request to https://api.mydomain/endpoint, it reaches my backend server on localhost:3210 as a GET request instead.
access log
[27/Oct/2024:10:29:16 +0100] "POST /api/v1/user/register HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.42.0"
[27/Oct/2024:10:29:18 +0100] "GET /api/v1/user/register HTTP/1.1" 404 35 "http://api.mydomain/api/v1/user/register" "PostmanRuntime/7.42.0"

Thanks very much!

Check the Nginx access log. You should see both the original POST request and the subsequent GET request.

Thank you, @RichardSmith. I checked the access logs and see that the initial POST request to /api/v1/dcsv1/user/register is redirected (301) to a GET request, resulting in a 404.

Look at t the response headers to that post request (to add to the question, use curl -I …. Is nginx emitting that redirect or the upstream app?

If the original POST was being sent to http by mistake, instead of https, that would explain the 301 and the downgrade to GET. If you change the return 301 ... in your Nginx config to return 307 .., that would keep POST through the redirection.

Enabling debug logging will help you see what nginx is doing.

@AD7six the default access log does not show if http or https was used. However, the referrer of the GET response is http which implies that the original POST was indeed http.

Hope that's clear. Just check weather frontend is curling to http ot https site. As you are rewriting 80 => 443 post may convert to get.
